# How to make a superview resize automatically same size and coordinate with its subview?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview

I have a `UIVIew` that contains an `UIImageView`. I want to make the `UIView` same size and same coordinate with the `UIImageView`. How can I do it?

Comment: You can use `AutoMasking` & Show your code.

Comment: why you didn't take imageview as background color of view ?is there any restrictions for doing like that?

Comment: set its frame as that of UIImageView.

Comment: Do you need programatically ? other wise you can use Xib

Comment: Thanks you guys a lot. This 's how I did it:
First, I converted the coordinate of UIImageView to self.view's coordinate. Then I set the UIView's frame equal to the actual frame the UIIMageView that's containing the Image. Then, I unchecked all autosizng properties. I attached code below.  

    `CGRect frame = [self.imageView convertRect:self.imageView.bounds toView:self.view];

   [self.imageView setFrame:AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(self.photo.size, frame)];

    [self.groundView setFrame:self.imageView.frame];`

Answer (score 1):

To auto resize programatically.

At first Uncheck the autoLayout here is the screen shot.

[image]

The add the code  for auto resize

>

```
         myView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        myView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: It wont do what he ask for?If it does please explain how

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//myview : UIView
//imageview:UIImageview
    CGRect frame1=myview.frame;
    CGRect frame2=imageView.frame;
    CGRect frame3=CGRectMake(frame1.origin.x+frame2.origin.x, frame1.origin.y+frame2.origin.y, frame2.size.width, frame2.size.height);
    [myview setFrame:frame3];
    [imageView setFrame:myView.bounds];
```